# Proactive message, botbuilder to FB messenger with messaging_type and tags in nodejs using Azure Functions

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-functions, facebook-messenger

In order to send FB messenger messages after 24 hour window shuts

This documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/message-tags

This code:

```
const { ActivityTypes, BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder');
    const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

module.exports = async function (context, req) {    
    if (!req.body) {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a conversation reference in the request body"
        };
        return;
    }
    var msg = { type: ActivityTypes.Message };
    msg.text = "hello"
    const conversationReference = req.body;
    await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {    
         await turnContext.sendActivity(msg);    
    });

    context.res = {
        body: 'Message sent!'
    };

};
```

I am trying to add the message tags and have tried:

```
 msg.sourceEvent({
    facebook: {
        messaging_type: 'MESSAGE_TAG',
        tag: 'ACCOUNT_UPDATE'
    }
});
```

but I get msg.sourceEvent is not a function. And also:

```
msg.messaging_type = 'MESSAGE_TAG';
msg.tag = 'ACCOUNT_UPDATE';
```

which does not work and continues with the failed behaviour of saving you are sending messages outside of the 24 hour window.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to [implement channel-specific functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) by using the activity object's `channelData` property.

```js
await turnContext.sendActivity({
    text: 'Hello!',
    channelData: {
        messaging_type: 'MESSAGE_TAG',
        tag: 'ACCOUNT_UPDATE'
    }
});
```

Comment: would `msg.channelData` also work? I would want to construct my message first.

Comment: @JDT, this is not related to the BotBuilder SDK, just basic javascript. As long as you pass an object that has the channelData property, it will work.